# redirect magento urls with random number

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have magento store and had issue with the url rewrites adding random numbers to the urls to some store categories.   The overall issue is fixed so the category urls are now correct but I want to redirect the effected urls back to it's correct url as some have been indexed by google

So category-1.html and category-22.html will redirect to .category.html

I have it working to some extent with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.*)-(?:[0-9]{1,2})\.html?/?$    [NC]
```

but there are some categories in the store that have urls like this

/0-39-95.html

and for these it causes a 404.   These urls were not effected by the particular issue.    For effected categories they all only had alpha in the url.    So I need the rewrite to only apply when there alpha before the dash but not apply if there are numbers before the dash

So redirect

/category-1.html  to /category.html
or  /category-21.html to /category.html

but not redirect

/category-41-60.html  or  /0-39-95.html 
 (anything with more than 1 set of numbers)

Answer (score 0):

try this `^/([a-zA-Z]*)-(?:[0-9]{1,2})\.html?/?$`